# How to renew a delegation token for a long running applications besides the time set in the hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, delegation, apache-apex

I have an Apache Apex application which runs on my Hadoop environment.

I have no problem with the application except that, it is failing after 7days. And, i realized that it is because of the cluster level setting for any application.

Is there any way, i can renew the delegation token perodically at some interval to ensure job runs continously without failing!!

I could find any resources online for on how to renew a hdfs delegation tokens!! Can someone please share your knowledge ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mentioned in the [Apex documentation](https://apex.apache.org/docs/apex/security/).
Also it offers 2 solution in detail. Non-intrusive for the Hadoop system would be to choose the 'Auto-refresh approach'.
Basically you need to copy your keytab file into HDFS and configure

```
<property>
    <name>dt.authentication.store.keytab</name>
    <value>hdfs-path-to-keytab-file</value>
</property>
```

in your *dt-site.xml*.

HTH